# Writing to a Firebase from within a Polymer element

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer

I am working on an assignment for a course in "Coding the Humanities" which involves writing a custom web component. This means I am required to use Polymer even though as far as I can see there is absolutely no added value to doing so.

I want to create a literal chat "room" in which users input a character to identify themselves and can walk around the room bumping into one another after the fashion of robotfindskitten.

My idea was to write each character and its position to a Firebase location, updating everyone's positions in real time, so I need the Firebase JS client- using `core-ajax` for REST requests isn't fast enough.

The [GitHub readme](https://github.com/Polymer/core-firebase) for the `core-firebase` element consists of a link to a [less than helpful component page](http://polymer.github.io/core-firebase/components/core-firebase/).

Looking at the `core-firebase` element itself, I don't see anything that corresponds to the 'value' event; `locationChanged` has a 'child-added' event handler, but that's it.

Am I crazy for thinking the `core-firebase` element is just very incomplete? Should I try to write my own 'value' handler? If so, do I just add it to the `locationChanged` property of the object passed to `Polymer()`? I'm very confused - I know enough JS that what's happening in the `core-firebase` code is straddling the limits of my comprehension. (Which might have to do with the `this` keyword, I don't know.) Any input here would be appreciated. (And yes, I've already remarked to the instructor that I could have handled this using plain old jQuery and Firebase if I didn't have to use Polymer. No word as yet on that.)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the commits](https://github.com/Polymer/core-firebase/commits/master) for core-firebase it looks like it's had about two days work on it plus some maintenance, so it wouldn't be surprising if there are missing features.

One nice part about Polymer is that it interops very well with other ways of writing apps. It's totally reasonable and supported to use jQuery and Firebase directly to read from firebase and react to changes. You can still make good use of polymer's templating and databinding by doing this within an element of your own and using Polymer's data binding, templating, and plain old DOM events to propagate those changes throughout your app and render them onto the page.

Comment: One thing I have noticed, though, is that jQuery and Polymer don't seem to play too well together - I know jQuery can't touch the shadow DOM, but there also seems to be a conflict with certain methods I try to call - I recall trying to concat() something and getting errors with platform.js.

Comment: Be sure to include platform.js before jquery. jQuery is ignorant of the shadow dom afaik which will cause a few problems, but it can still work. e.g. $($('my-element')[0].shadowRoot).find('.something-within-shadow-dom'). In my experience though, once I've started using polymer I haven't needed jQuery much for dom manipulation.